# Open FileDescriptor for reading and writing with a Channel

Tags: java

I have a `FileDescriptor` and would like to open it for reading and writing using a single channel. I can use streams like so to get one channel for reading, and one channel for writing, but I would prefer a single channel.

```
FileChannel in = new FileInputStream(fd).getChannel();
FileChannel out = new FileOutputStream(fd).getChannel();
```

Comment: Why? [Applications should not create their own file descriptors.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileDescriptor.html)

Comment: I'm implementing a VPNService on android, it provides me with the FileDescriptors.

Answer (score 0):

Been working with `FileChannel` recently, yes you can use 1 `FileChannel` for reading and writing as long as you use methods that do not modify the channel's `position`. In fact this is the only way you will have a consistent view of the file as write may be paged/cached by the OS that is yet to be "visible" from the other reader at least before flush.
This is excerpt from the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html)

> File channels are safe for use by multiple concurrent threads. The
>   close method may be invoked at any time, as specified by the Channel
>   interface. Only one operation that involves the channel's position or
>   can change its file's size may be in progress at any given time;
>   attempts to initiate a second such operation while the first is still
>   in progress will block until the first operation completes. **Other
>   operations, in particular those that take an explicit position, may
>   proceed concurrently**; whether they in fact do so is dependent upon the
>   underlying implementation and is therefore unspecified.

I use single threaded write (that changes `position`) and multithreaded reads (that do not change `position` ie. `read(ByteBuffer dst, long position)`)

Cheers